# HTTP Error 500.1013 - Internal Server Error While uploading more than 250 mb files IIS node in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, iisnode

[click here for error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIMok.png)

my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear />
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <iisnode enableXFF="true" maxRequestBufferSize="52428800" loggingEnabled="true" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Node app">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097152000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   <webSocket enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

the above code works fine in less than 250 files, but we have an error above 250 MB files

Comment: Can you switch to Azure App Service on Linux/Docker to host your Node.js apps? The project iisnode has been out-of-maintenance for two years, and you really shouldn't spend time on that.

Comment: We have using Linux/Docker to host our Node.js application, do you have any idea from that issue..? please suggest me

Comment: Did you happen to resolve this issue? I am having the same issue.